# How to pass more than one column as a parameter to Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to pass more than one column name as a parameter to dataframe.

```scala
val readData = spark.sqlContext
  .read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter",",")
  .schema(Schema)
  .load("emp.csv")

val cols_list1 = "emp_id,emp_dt"
val cols_list2 = "emp_num"

val RemoveDupli_DF = readData
  .withColumn("rnk", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(s"$cols_list1").orderBy(s"$cols_list2") ))
```

Above code is working, if i have one column name , whereas with two or more columns, its giving below error.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`emp_id,emp_dt`'

Using Scala 2.x version.

Answer (score 1):

The `partitionBy` method as multiple signatures:

```scala
def partitionBy(colName: String, colNames: String*)
// or
def partitionBy(cols: Column*)
```

Your code is providing the list of columns as a single string which will fail because there is no column called `emp_id,emp_dt`. Hence, you get the error message.

You could define your column names (as Strings) in a collection

```scala
val cols_seq1 = Seq("emp_id","emp_dt")
```

and then call partitionsBy like this:

```scala
Window.partitionBy(cols_seq1: _*)
```

The notation `: _*` tells the compiler to pass each element of `cols_seq1` as its own argument into the `partitionBy` call rather than all of it as a single argument.

As an alternative you could also just use

```scala
Window.partitionBy("emp_id", "emp_dt")
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for the response.

I am Getting the similar issue as per above inputs and i tried like below.

val cols_list1 = Seq(col("emp_id"),col("emp_dt"))

val checkDupli = readData.withColumn("rnk", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(s"$cols_list1").orderBy(s"$cols_list2") ))

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`List(emp_id, emp_dt)`' given input columns:

Note: emp_id and emp_dt columns are part of my data frame readData

Not sure, what's going wrong here.

Appreciate if any other working solution is there.

Comment: I think to get spark to expand your list, Iyou need to use `cols_seq1:_*`.